# Apache 2 - LDAP/Active Directory - Automatic login/authentication process

Tags: windows, apache, authentication, active-directory

Is there a fully automated way to authentication a user using IE8+ with Apache **without** the user having to enter any form of credentials?
Running IIS is not really an option even tho i'm running Windows.

I've found some Perl based solutions that should work but i could only get it to work on *Nix with a LOT of fuzzing around.

I'm currently using authnz_ldap_module which works great, but the users are really cranky and annoyed by having to put in their user-id and password for each new session that they open.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should probably note: i HAVE googled, but 99.9% of all the hits were for *Nix systems and the rest was just junk from what i could tell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've been having the same problem myself today after eventually getting the `mod_authnz_ldap` module to work.

From my research thus far, I gather you can't do seamless signon with the `mod_authnz_ldap` module and you'll have to use `mod_auth_sspi` instead. I've tried this out and it seems to work as expected (on Internet Explorer anyway - you can also configure Firefox to pass through by modifying the `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` key).

Here's the steps:

1. Download the mod_auth_sspi module from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/
2. From the zip file's bin folder, copy mod_auth_sspi.so to your apache modules folder
3. From the zip file's bin folder, copy sspipkgs.exe to your apache bin folder
4. Edit httpd.conf so that the Directory is configured something like this:

> ```
>  Alias /secure "C:/Secure"
>  <Directory "C:/Secure">
>  Order deny,allow
>  Allow from all
>
>  AuthType SSPI
>  SSPIAuth On
>  SSPIOfferBasic on
>  SSPIBasicPreferred On
>  SSPIAuthoritative Off
>  AuthName "Login"
>  SSPIDomain dc.domain
>
>  Require valid-user
>  </Directory>
> ```

Now restart Apache.

Unfortunately, after all that it's no good for me as a solution as I have multiple LDAP servers to authenticate against, but hopefully this will help you.

Comment: I'll try this ASAP when i get back into the office! Looks promising!

Comment: Honestly mate, don't know what i'd do without you right now.
From the bottom of my heart, thank you! And GL with your endeavors!

Comment: I've had plenty of help over the last couple of years from Stack Overflow answers. I'm glad I could help someone else out for a change.

Comment: anyone getting "invalid ELF header" when adding the module in an RHEL environment?