# apache - website - windows authentication

Tags: windows, apache, authentication, web

I would like to use my Windows credentials to log on to my website. I don't want something like LDAP. Let's say I log in to my Windows account and then I enter the URL of my website. When I hit enter, I want to be automatically logged on into website with the current Windows user session.

How can I do this?

From my researches, apache mod_auth_sspi may solve my problem but I'm not really sure that my scenario will be exactly like I described it.

I've even heard that there may be some problems with browsers. Basically I need to make it work in IE. Then I'll have to take care of the other browsers if it's possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache 2 - LDAP/Active Directory - Automatic login/authentication process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105816/apache-2-ldap-active-directory-automatic-login-authentication-process)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SimpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/) if you are not adverse to PHP.